# List Filter not Working in Realm Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, realm

I have a realm List I want apply a query on the List but app is crashing and am unable to find the bug. Please help me Thanks.

```
var numbersDetail = List is type of ContactDetail()

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: ContactDetail.NUMBER + " = %@", formattedNumber!)

let realmContactDetail = numbersDetail.filter(predicate).first
```

Comment: use like this: 
`let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NUMBER = %@", formattedNumber!)
let realmContactDetail = numbersDetail.filter(predicate)`

Comment: i am fetching same issue -
throw RLMException("This method may only be called on RLMArray instances retrieved from an RLMRealm");

Comment: You seem to have asked this question twice! I've put an answer on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592305/realm-list-filter-swift