# Realm List Filter Swift

Tags: swift, realm

```
var numbersDetail = List is type of ContactDetail()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: ContactDetail.NUMBER + " = %@", formattedNumber!)
let realmContactDetail = numbersDetail.filter(predicate).first
```

Fetching ERROR :

> throw RLMException("This method may only be called on RLMArray
>   instances retrieved from an RLMRealm");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs if you try and perform a query on a Realm Swift `List` object (Which are actually Objective-C `RLMArray` objects under the hood) before its parent object has been added to a `Realm`.

```
class Person: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var picture: NSData? = nil // optionals supported
  let dogs = List<Dog>()
}

let dog = Dog()
dog.name = "Rex"

let person = Person()
person.dogs.append(dog)

let rex = person.dogs.filter("name == 'Rex'") // QUERY WILL TRIGGER EXCEPTION AT THIS POINT

let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(person)
}

let rex = person.dogs.filter("name == 'Rex'") // Query will now work as expected
```

In a nutshell, you need to make sure that `numbersDetail` belongs to a `Realm` before you perform that query. You can easily test this by checking `numbersDetail.realm != nil`.